# Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-insomnia"

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to build my project but its fails with following error :

"Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova prepare (exit code 1):

```
    Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-insomnia" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
    Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-insomnia" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again.
    Error: Failed to fetch plugin
    cordova-plugin-insomnia@git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git via registry.
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    npm ERR! git clone
    C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-EddyVerbruggen-Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin-git-223
```

I tried installing cordova plugin using:

1. $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-insomnia $ npm install
       --save @ionic-native/insomnia
2. cordova plugin add
   https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
3. npm i cordova-plugin-insomnia

but, none of the command works.

Error generated as :

> npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-EddyVerbruggen-Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin-git-223bcd2c
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6956-d2de50d1\git-cache-d4203f45\8d2c3b01fc0c11d9bc36bc1b5f9a141bd097f908
>   npm ERR! Cloning into
>   'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6956-d2de50d1\git-cache-d4203f45\8d2c3b01fc0c11d9bc36bc1b5f9a141bd097f908'...
>   npm ERR! git-upload-pack
>   'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-EddyVerbruggen-Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin-git-223bcd2c':
>   git-upload-pack: command not found
>   npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   npm ERR! and the repository exists.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Workspace\XXXXXX-mobile-app\node_modules\npm-debug.log
>   will push strings array {"name":"lang","titles":["English (US)","English (UK)"],"values":["en-us","en-gb"]}
>   android preferences file was successfully generated
>   ios settings bundle was successfully generated

I'm using following versions -

1. Node: v7.4.0
2. NPM: v4.0.5
3. Git: v1.9.5
4. Ionic: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this post has been quite old yet if anyone searching for the answer:

I did removed npm package and cordova plugin for insomnia.
Then, `ionic cordova prepare`.
Finally, again added both - package and plugin.

Don't know, what was breaking, but it worked.

*Note: I was using ionic 3 at that time. New version (v5) may have package updates.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not always the solution, but in similar cases, I simply run a little `npm update`, and it's ok. 
Eventually, you should do a
`ionic cordova platform remove ...` and then `ionic cordova platform add ...`.